# Aws Glue job to push data to redshift constantly

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a table (in s3) that has records dumped in it and is based on the partition of 'year','month','day'. I wanted to dump this data from the glue catalogue (as I have run a crawler on it) database to redshift.
So creating a bookmark and using the columns 'year','month','day', will work?
The reason I have this doubt is because, I thought the identifiers of the data must be unique and as there are multiple records for a day, then the date columns arent unique

Answer (score 1):

Redshift won't cause any issue with duplicated data. You can define primary key constraints but they are [informational only](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_best-practices-defining-constraints.html).

By the way, you might consider using an [external table](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c-getting-started-using-spectrum.html) using Spectrum rather than trying to manage highwatermarks? With an external table the data would automatically always be up-to-date, and queries can also take advantage of partition pruning as documented [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/10-best-practices-for-amazon-redshift-spectrum/).